# Rails: Getting the Relation without where or limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

If I do `Product.where(title: "asdf")`, I get an Relation object. Some time later, I can do an `each` on that object, and at this point, the query gets executed. But sometimes, I want all the objects, so I won't need a `where` clause or something. I do `Product.all` then, but this will execute the query immediately. If it turns out, that I won't need the products in the view, the query was unnecessary. I could do `Product.where("1=1")`, but it doesn't feel right.

Is there some kind of `Product.relation` or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `scoped` should do the trick. [See doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scoped).